# I can't delete files 'rm: cannot remove X Read-only file system'

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, rdiff-backup

I am trying to remove an rdiff backup folder as some problems occured during the backup and need to remove it's history and try again. However, when I run:

```
rm -r -f rdiff-backup-data
```

I get the following on some of the files:

```
rm: cannot remove `X': Read-only file system
```

Here is what I get when I run mount:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/usbdisk type ext3 (rw)
```

So that shows the drive is rw?

ls -la /media/usbdisk gives the following:

```
[root@localhost v5]# ls -la /media/usbdisk
total 36
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 Mar 31  2010 .
drwxrwxrwx  9 root root  4096 Dec 15  2009 ..
drwxrwxrwx 39  501  501  4096 Aug 19 09:04 development-backup
drwx------  2 root root 16384 Mar 30  2010 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  501  4096 Aug 19 00:00 officeshare-backup
```

Anyone know what is going on and how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

found out the drive was ro in /proc/mounts so ran the remount command mentioned below and got the following:

```
ext3_abort called.
EXT3-fs error (device sda1): ext3_remount: Abort forced by user
mount: block device LABEL=USBDISK1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
ext3_abort called.
EXT3-fs error (device sda1): ext3_remount: Abort forced by user
```

Comment: Can you posts the ouput of `mount`?

Comment: sometime this message might show due to file system corrupted. following this link to resolve filesystem related issue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020872/busybox-initramfs-again-and-again/1021087#1021087

Comment: Thanks for linking the above. The basic idea is to run fsck ^

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depending on the state of things, the output of `mount` may not reflect reality.  You're far better of with `cat /proc/mounts`, which is guaranteed to show you the actual mount table, wherein you'll probably find that it's actually mounted read-only.  You can fix this with `mount -o remount,rw /mount/point`.  If that command errors out, then your filesystem is hosed in some way; a `fsck` (at the very least) is in order.  You don't need to stop the entire system to fsck a partition, just that partition needs to be unmounted.

Comment: cheers, now i just need to know http://serverfault.com/questions/304422/can-i-run-fsck-on-a-partition-which-is-unmounted-but-on-a-live-machine (can i run fsck, if unmounted but users might still try to access using its mount location)

Answer (score 16):

You could try remounting the device and seeing where that leads

```
mount -o remount,rw /media/usbdisk
```

If that doesn't work then you'll probably need to fsck the device

```
umount /dev//media/usbdisk
fsck /dev/sdb1
```

You may need to use the -f option to umount for force it to be unmounted though.

Comment: Can you run fsck on a partition if other partitions are mounted and running? That won't cause any problems? I have read that its best to go into single-user mode and don't allow any changes.

Comment: You are safe to run fsck on unmounted devices. If it really bothers you though, as this is a USB device, you can always unplug it and  use a different system to fsck it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is an another workaround to it,

Reboot your linux into recovery mode and you will get an option for **clean boot** which actually serves the purpose of freeing some space, incase the disk is full. This will unmount and remount in read-write state.

Then you can use the terminal **root option** to use the terminal and delete the required files without actually booting.

Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Your update included this line of output:

```
mount: block device LABEL=USBDISK1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

This error should be pretty self-explanatory. The physical device is read-only, so a filesystem on it cannot be mounted as writeable.

If the device is a flash drive, this may mean that it has reached its end of life and needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

rm: cannot remove `.s.PGSQL.5438.lock': Read-only file system

for this error message during startup the DB/instances

Work around is to reboot the host/server